# Bitmap.Comp() method in android. Quality = 100 gives image larger in size than original image

Tags: android, image, bitmap, image-compression

I am using Bitmap's `compress()` method to compress my images with the help of following code:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos;
Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgs[i].getAbsolutePath());
img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, compFactor, baos);
byte[] compImgBytes;
compImgBytes = baos.toByteArray();
OutputStream out1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(
        new File(dir.getString("dir", null) + File.separator +
        String.valueOf(imgsName) + ".jpg")));
out1.write(compImgBytes);
```

Problem is, when I use 100 as a compression factor (`compFactor = 100`) for this code, the size of the resultant image is larger than the image being compressed. All I was trying to do was compress the image with max quality as per Android documentation for the Bitmap class.

Why is the resultant image's size greater than original image's size? Am I missing something?

Comment: The original image was already compressed, as AFAIK the only file formats Android works with are compressed ones (PNG, JPEG). Depending on the file format and quality rating of the original image, it is well within reason that a 100-quality JPEG will be larger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing in `100` for the quality indicates:

> 100 meaning compress for max quality

So that means the compressor will do very little compression of the raw bytes...  the images you are loading are presumably saved with more compression.  Thus your newly compressed image is larger than your original images.

Comment: Since, JPEG is a compressed format, so the raw bytes that  you are referring to there are of uncompressed image?

Comment: Yeah.  You're calling `decodeFile` which uncompresses the image in memory.  Then `compress` takes the in-memory bytes and compresses them.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance @Buddy! This was really helpful!